# Is Mace Windu Finn's father?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, star-wars-finn

Finn knows nothing about his family because he was taken while he was very little.

But a black main character makes me think (not being racist guys). And when he used the lightsaber I thought that he had a Jedi parent. Master Windu is the only black Jedi we know so is there any canon explanation to that? Is it right?

Comment: See also [this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111343/is-there-any-evidence-that-lando-calrissian-is-finns-father).

Comment: close voters: the dupe, while similar in spirit, asks about a different character from a different generation, so the answers will be different.

Comment: Why can't he just have no Jedi backstory? We're talking about a universe where an untrained Force user magically learns the mind trick - a former stormtrooper (with weapons and close quarters combat experience and training) wielding a lightsaber proficiently should be the least of our worries.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Mace can't be Finn's father because Mace dies at the hands of Palpatine.  It would make Finn older than Luke and Leia. MAYBE a grandchild, but I have a feeling that there's too many Force-sensitive folks in the movie already. My theory is that Finn is Lando's son. In part of the EU, Lando and Han flee and become smugglers once again. It's been rumored that Lando will make an appearance in the next film, but more importantly, there are character parallels between Finn and Lando. They were both supporting the Empire/first order until a major event occurred. they both were self centered an opportunistic in the beginning, looking for an easy way out (helping Darth Vader/only looking for a way to escape the empire) and both came back to help fight against the forces of evil.

There's also a rumor going around about Han being Finn's father, but it would be a stretch to make it fit with the ever increasing complexities of the story line as it is, but it would explain why Leia and Han were separated in Episode VII and were awkward with each other — because Han had a previous wife, Sana.

Comment: What does this answer say that older existing answers don't?

Answer (score 14):

It cannot possibly be Mace Windu, because Mace died at the end of Clone wars, at the year 32BBY, and the events of TFA happen 66 years after that, meaning that Finn would have to be at least 65 years old in the film (barring artificial insemination after father's death).

He clearly looks WAY younger than 65.

---

**UPDATE:**

While this is more of a speculation than direct evidence, there is a SMALL chance that Finn's father is... **drum roll**:

> ***Han Solo!***

The basis for this theory is the fact that, according to New Disney canon (specifically, Marvel's 2015 *Star Wars* comics), [Sana Starros](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sana_Starros) - a dark skinned woman - showed up at some point before and some point after Battle of Yavin and claimed that she was

> Han Solo's wife to Princess Leia Organa (which Han denied!)

It is *possible* (though in my opinion not very likely) that this was a hook which Disney used to later reveal that he was Finn's father, his mother being Sana Starros.

Answer (score 4):

In the *SW:TFA* trailers, Finn is shown wielding the lightsaber like he knows what he is doing.  But in the actual film,

> he does not use the Force at all.  He is not Force-sensitive.  He just swings the lightsaber around like any other kind of melee weapon.  Later in the film, we see who the real Force-sensitive is, who ends up wielding the lightsaber like a real Jedi ... Rey.

So it is very unlikely that Finn has any Jedi parentage at all.  So, that leads back to the mystery that we don't know *anything* about his real parentage.

Comment: It's been a week since I saw TFA, but I remember that I had the impression that Rey wields the lightsaber much more like someone who is used to fighting with a staff (isn't she mostly stabbing?) than like a Jedi.

Comment: She has experience with a staff, and that would certainly influence her fighting style. But she also swings and blocks with it like a swordfighter, too. Also, the lightsaber calls to her in Maz Kanata's cantina, and she has a Force vision when she touches it for the first time. Later, she uses the Force to call the lightsaber to her during her fight with Kylo Ren.  So she has a connection to it in the Force, like a Jedi would.

Comment: I don't doubt that Rey has a connection to the force and uses it in the battle, but I'm not convinced that Finn has no connection to the force just because he can't wield the lightsaber as well as her. Anyway, that discussion rather belongs to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111797/is-finn-a-force-wielder

Answer (score -1):

Finn is the son of Luke. We don't know what's happened since he isolated himself, and with that much of a plot blank, it leaves open the possibility that this is the unveiling of Finn's parentage.  There's been a lot of talk that Rey would be Luke's daughter.  I actually think Rey is the granddaughter of Obi Wan.  This is why she is so strong in the Force.

The lurking glance that Kylo Ren gives Finn on the planet is quite telling.  There is some level of recognition occurring.  Also, and I don't know how many people caught on to it- but during the movie, Leia embraces Rea- and it seemed more than just a basic hug.  There was a familiarity to it- so there's definitely history there.

There is evidence to show that Finn is force-sensitive.  He resisted the training from the StormTrooper Program, he has good intuition, strong reflexes and had no trouble wielding the lightsaber. He also seems tied to the force (even though everything is), he has a respect for it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! Do you have any evidence for this? Answers here are generally expected to have some kind of backup and not be just fan theories. Have you taken our [tour]?

Answer (score -2):

I think Luke is Finn's father.  Finn has the force through Luke and is a cousin to Rey who is the daughter of Han and Leia.

Comment: This is a great start to an answer.  Do you have a source?