# Is there any evidence that Lando Calrissian is Finn's father?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, star-wars-finn

After watching *Star Wars: The Force Awakens* I heard people claiming that Lando Calrissian is Finn's father. Is there any evidence that he actually is or counter-evidence that he's not?

Comment: Maybe reword this to avoid spoilers?

Comment: @KevinSuttle Can you be more concrete? I don't see any spoilers. The question is just about a character (Finn) you can see in trailers and on posters, and does not reveal anything about the movie's actual plot.

Comment: @AlecTeal what original research? People have been baselessly speculating that Finn "must be" Lando's son since literally 5 seconds after the first trailer hit YouTube.

Comment: @CreationEdge I shall tell the guy to please kindly leave.

Comment: @CreationEdge TL;DR but the second sentence, you are claiming that what has been said isn't a spoiler, maybe I'm not the YouTube spud that you are. Now stop making it worse.

Comment: Side note: If there is evidence, [Maury Povich has it](http://blogs.babycenter.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/Maury-Povich.jpg).

Comment: Got rid of the spoiler protocols because there is no evidence that the posited relationship exists, which means it isn't a spoiler at all. Spoiler = revealing a significant fact or event from a work to people who might not know about it yet.  This is neither a fact nor an event from TFA, just a possibility.

Comment: In that case it should be worded as "is it possible" rather than is it proven. For example, right after episode 5 aired: " Is there any evidence that Vader is Luke's father?" . And you potentially just spoiled or make people feel spoiled and be on a cliffhanger until the end of the movie

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No, there is no definite evidence either way yet.

For all we know from the movie, Finn never knew his real parents. They may be anyone. Maybe we will never know them.

So far, I have seen two arguments that support "Finn is Lando's son" theory.

First, Lando is about the only human with dark skin in original trilogy. Some people think that relative rarity of humans with different pigmentation makes them all related in some way. Going down this way of thinking, the "obvious" conclusion is that Finn must be Lando's family - most likely son. The same way of thinking tells us that Finn is son of [Han and Sana](http://womenwriteaboutcomics.com/2015/06/06/star-wars-6-reveals-new-wife-for-han-solo-and-shes-a-black-woman/), dark-skinned female human introduced in comic book.

Second, Lawrence Kasdan (co-writer of new movies) said that "[Lando I don’t think is finished in any way, shape, or form](http://www.vanityfair.com/hollywood/2015/05/lawrence-kasdan-star-wars-force-awakens)".

The first argument ignores Mace Windu, another dark-skinned human, who was introduced in prequel trilogy. Mace Windu, being a Jedi, most likely never had a child, but he must have had some parents and might have some sibling, so maybe that family line eventually lead down to Finn. Out of universe, the whole argument is pretty racist.

The second argument probably reads too much into Lawrence's words. He was also contracted to co-write spin-off about young Han Solo, and we know from *Empire Strikes Back* that Han and Lando had some history together. Lawrence could as well mean that we will see Lando in spin-off movie.

So, I guess it's up to you to decide which side is more convincing to you. If you look for strong, factual, canonical evidence, then the current answer is that we know nothing about Finn's family.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer. According to http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/111268/57606 Mace Windu logically can't be the father.

Comment: Obviously Finn is the son of Lando and Leia, which is why Han didn't like to talk to either anymore...

Comment: I don't understand why you played the racist card. Everyone assumed at the start that Kylo was Han's son, yet, Luky, Rey, Anakin, Obi-wan, unnamedcharacter#1 and several others are caucasian. I wonder if Finn was Green and short, if you'd call it racism for associating him to Yoda. Heck if he looked like a lobster, would you be expecting him to yell "it's a trap!" ?

Comment: @Oak Sorry, but I don't think that comments are appropriate place to discuss racial issues of Star Wars franchise. If you [search the web](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=star+wars+racism), you will find much more than you ever wished for.

Comment: Precisely, likewise the arguments that are based on 'racist premises' are totally uncalled for, as i've explained already

Comment: @oak You might be overreacting to a light-hearted comment riffing on the old "these people from a minority look alike, therefore they're related" cliche. Relax. No-one's "playing a card" of any kind.

Answer (score 5):

There is some evidence, although not canonical: on Amazon you can buy [a jigsaw puzzle](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0153YLTIY) of Finn which formerly claimed (you can see it mentioned in the reviews and in [this article](http://screenrant.com/star-wwars-force-awakens-finn-lando-calrissian/)) that he is Lando Calrissian's son:

[image]

Sadly they seem to have removed this from their product description, since I can't find it anywhere. And there's an article [here](http://makingstarwars.net/2015/11/about-that-star-wars-the-force-awakens-son-of-lando-rumor-its-false/) by Jason Ward of Making Star Wars, who believes this is **not** real evidence at all and that the puzzle seller simply made a mistake.

---

A piece of more canonical but also more circumstantial evidence is that Billy Dee Williams, who played Lando in the original trilogy, [has said](http://screenrant.com/star-wars-7-sequels-spinoffs-billy-dee-williams-lando/) that he may also star in the new trilogy:

> “Yeah, people were pretty upset about it.  But I uh…I may very well…I have a feeling I’m going to show up. There’s nothing I can really discuss about it at this stage.”

Again, not solid evidence, since he could be showing up simply as an old character rather than as a relative of a new one. But note that he just says he "has a feeling" he'll show up, which suggests there's some compelling reason that he should, which he can't make public. Being an old companion of other recurring stars clearly can't be the motivator he's thinking of, but being related to one of the new stars very well could be!

Comment: Re: #2: I was going to say that you can't really trust that scoundel/conman's claims, but then I realized **I was not inside Star Wars universe**.

Comment: @DVK That's always a good thing to keep in mind ;-)

Comment: Considering how some characters decided to resolve their personal problems, Lando and the skills/history he has just might be needed down the road.

Answer (score -1):

Just throwing this out there. Like most people, I would love to see Lando return in Episode 8. And like most people, the possibility of Finn being Lando's son has crossed my mind more than once. Though it didn't initially enter my mind purely out of connecting race dots, but because of what Maz Kanata said to Finn in Episode 7. Something along the lines of: "If you live long enough, you see the same eyes in different people. I'm looking at the eyes of a man who wants to run."

Now it's very likely she was simply addressing Finn's unwillingness to fight the baddies, but keeping in mind her "different people with the same eyes" remark, it does sound an awful lot like she's referring to what Finn has in common with Lando. Finn wanted to run, and Lando was willing to bend to the will of the empire, and even betray his friend in the process, rather than fight back.

Not going to say I firmly believe this theory. Just saying it's the only convincing clue I've come across to support it.